# WebView local link

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a WebView which reads local html file. It is a big file, so it is scrollable. I also have a link within WebView which leads to another local html file, which is a lot smaller file. When I enter that link, scroll position from first file is transferred to second file. So, second file is same size (height) as first file. I tried entering an outside link(www link) and it opens normally.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using: webView.setScrollX(int) and webView.setScrollY(int)

Comment: thanks! but still, "long" scroll does exist and it shouldn't be!

Comment: Solved problem. Apparently previous programmer put WebView into ScrollView in fragment layout. Sorry, should've seen it earlier.